# Android Layout_weight

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-linearlayout

Maybe I misunderstood the layout_weight parameter but I can't get it why something like this is not working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:background="@color/apr_blue"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:background="@color/apr_brightyellow"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:background="@color/apr_yellow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have three or more textviews within a LinearLayout. 
I want to place them in columns with a percentage width.
And that is what it produces:

With layout_weight setted to 0.3 / 0.2 / 0.5

[image: Android layout_weight incorrectly]

Then I varied the layout_weight parameters just a bit as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:background="@color/apr_blue"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:background="@color/apr_brightyellow"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:background="@color/apr_yellow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And now I get it as I wanted:

With layout_weight setted to 0.3 / 0.2 / 0.5

[image: Android layout_weight correctly]

is it a bug or maybe I really misunderstood the whole thing about layout_weight?

Comment: Try changing android:weightSum="1" to android:weightSum="1.0"
Weight sum should be a floating point value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `android:layout_weight` you should set `android:layout_width="0dp"` (in case when vertical orientation - `android:layout_height="0dp"`).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

try this....

```
        <TextView
            android:background="#F2e"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
             android:background="#F6e"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
             android:background="#F45"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```